# Use Pseudo Element to Create Background Overlay

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

My goal is to have a div with any background, which then uses a pseudo element to create a transparent white overlay, thus "lightening" the background of the div.  The "overlay" must be UNDER the contents of the div, though.  So, in the following example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Hello, World</h1>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 250px;
}
.container::before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
```

The `.content` `div` should not be "underneath" the white overlay, aka `.container::before`.

I would prefer not having to use `z-index` on `.content`, but I can if that is the only solution.

End goal: The red should be covered while the text and blue are not.

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1c5j9n4x/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If the pseudo element has a `z-index`, then you would need to position the `.content` element and add a `z-index` value to [establish a stacking context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hepxzmkj/)

```
.content {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

..you *could* also remove the `z-index` from the pseudo element and then merely position the `.content` element. In doing so, none of the elements need a `z-index`. The reason this works is because the `:before` pseudo element is essentially a previous sibling element. Thus, the succeeding `.content` element is positioned on top.

[**Alternative Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xbb9Lo48/)

```
.content {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
.container::before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
```

Comment: Every element has a default z-index of 1. So it doesn't need to be explicitly. In other words, the reason this solution works has nothing to do with Z-index, it is because the `position: relative;` was moved to the `.content` block which is the parent element where the `::before` element would be inserted. OP put the `position: relative` on the `.container` which the `::before` element would be along-side of, not inside-of. So the `::before` element had nothing to "attach" to. So this answer is correct, but not for the reasons explained in the answer. Move `position:relative` to the parent el

Comment: @jacurtis - No, that is false... every element has a default `z-index` of `auto` which behaves much differently than `1`; read the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#layered-presentation).