# CSS overlay over image background

Tags: css, overlay

I want to have an overlay over my image background, in order to see the white text above the image more clearly.

Why won't [this solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBJErm) work ?

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="bg1 image-cover">
  <p>H</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-size:  100px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.image-cover:before {
    content:'\A';
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    opacity: 1;
}

.bg1 {
  background-size: cover;
  background:  url('https://2zpt4dwruy922flhqyznip50-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/lock-and-stock-photos.jpg');
}
```

while [this one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNMZRp) does:

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="bg1">
  <div class="image-cover">
    <p>H</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
...

.image-cover {
    content:'\A';
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    opacity: 1;
}

...
```

I think I am misunderstanding the way `:before` works, but I am not fan of the second solution as it has one more div than the first.

Comment: You can see this [here][1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121731/use-pseudo-element-to-create-background-overlay

Comment: I have had a look at this solution but it seems to require `z-index` two elements to create a stacking context. As the `:before` element comes "before" the element, I would expect it to be stacked under above or under the text. But as it is positioned as absolute, it should appear behind the text.

Comment: @randomDownvoter why?  This is an honest question, and something that can be very confusing.   **+** 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm glad you're already aware of the second solution; this tends to be the approach I normally use (though not for any particular reason). You can simply modify your original approach as follows and get the desired effect:

```
#myDiv > p {
  position: relative;
}
```

Namely, give the nested `<p>` tag a non-`static` position value. See here: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/IsenrichO/pen/MbpQzJ)

Comment: You are a genius ! Thanks a thousand times (but can only upvote you once) :D I should have a CSS reset that sets divs to `position: relative` by default :) This is such an easy mistake, which probably comes from my lack of understanding of the `position: relative` vs. default positioning of DOM elements.

Comment: Glad I could help. And you're right, it's an easily fixed mistake in this case. For that reason, I often set some top-level style declaration in my stylesheet to address this: `div, p { position: relative; }`. Obviously, there are many instances where elements (more often a `<div>` than a `<p>` element) requires `absolute` positioning, but you can just create a new class to handle this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just increase the `z-index` of the text which is to be overlaid over the image like this:

```
#myDiv{
    z-index: 1;
}

#myDiv p{
    z-index: 2; /* should be more than the z-index of the background */
}
```