# Rectangular Overlay Over Image With CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to get a black square overlay over an image (with text inside it) just with HTML and CSS.

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727789/css-overlay-over-image-background), it looks like you're supposed to wrap the image with an element, and then style the wrapper so that it gets these styles:

```
content:'\A';
position: absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
opacity: 1;
```

So that is what I've tried, but nothing's happening.

https://jsfiddle.net/8qwy6m1s/1/

```css
.learn-more-options-row {
    display: flex;
}

.learn-more-options-image-wrapper {
    width: 33.33333%;
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    opacity: 1;
}

.learn-more-options-image {
    width: 33.333333%;
    outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline-offset: -10px;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: transform .2s;
}

.learn-more-options-image:hover {
    transform: scale(1.02);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="learn-more-options-row">
  <div class="learn-more-options-image-wrapper">
    <img class="learn-more-options-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/FAxdhjp.png" alt="buck knives warranty" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I'm ultimately going for:

[image]

I'll eventually want to get some text to appear over the overly, but I'm just trying to get the black overlay square to appear first.

I've also tried using `::before`, but that's not doing anything either:

https://jsfiddle.net/8qwy6m1s/2/

Comment: on each example you are missing something. Pseudo element require content:"" to work so both need to be there

Comment: you need to add position relative to the container of your absolute element, but I think your absolute element looks like it should be a pseudo element

Comment: @TemaniAfif okay - I've tried adding `content:""` to the pseudo element version, with no result: [https://jsfiddle.net/xq4jtuvm/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/xq4jtuvm/1/)

@Pete I've also tried changing `position: absolute` to `position: relative` on the container, but it's causing the background to appear behind the image, instead of in-front: [https://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2go1/](https://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2go1/)

Comment: For anyone who's interested, here's how I solved it:

https://jsfiddle.net/qhz6m5w8/

The key was to place the image and div within a container div that is positioned `relative` and then position the overlay div as `absolute`.  Place the overlay text as a span inside the overlay div, and position that as `absolute` as well.

Comment: don't add an answser inside the question also using an extra div is not different from using pseudo element. The same technique can be used for both